# Rails bug? Model form with datetime_select can't set default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Has anyone come across this? I can't set the defaults for my time with the form while it is associated with my model

e.g.

```
<%= f.datetime_select :date_start, { default: @event.date_start.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone), ampm: true, use_short_month: true, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year+1, minute_step: 5}, class: 'form-control form-control-date' %>
```

The reason I need defaults because it defaults to utc. I need the edit form to factor in the time zone otherwise the user will see the wrong time they entered.

As it is, it ignores the default completely and leave it in UTC. This is an issue in the edit form.

If I change it to a tag, the default works. However I would need to change all my forms to tag so the form submits properly.

Anyone have a fix besides possibly doing that?

Comment: I believe default is not used if your object already have a value, is it your case?

Comment: that's correct. but i want that value in the user's time zone, so I need to override it or find another way around it

Comment: Well obviously you need to act at the object level, not at the tag level

Comment: I don't think that's right, unless you can suggest otherwise. time saved in the model is saved in utc. the preferred way to handle time is to leave that untouched and to show the time in the user's time zone (usually altered in the view)